# Node JS Type ORM migration generate command getting error

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am trying to generate a new migration file running the command below:

`docker exec -it app_container ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n init`

I'm getting follwing error during migration generation:

> { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/service/src/migration/1641991263631-init.ts'
> errno: -13,
> code: 'EACCES',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: '/service/src/migration/1641991263631-init.ts'
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running it with sudo/admin priviledges worked for me. (If you didn't do that, try it!)

Comment: I have tried with sudo, but showing the same error.